# Exact Target - Individual Email Result object - set Lookup to IER records in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, lookup, salesforce-id, externalid

Apparently Exact Target "uses" Stack Exchange for support issues.  More specifically, they have no developer support, and their API is "as-is", and either way I believe I have this isolated to a non-API possibility.

I have waited two weeks for the Product Manager and our Account Representative to help - that's been a loss of time.   I talked to Premier Support for 30 minutes today, and we navigated their Help site, to no avail.

---

When sending an email inside Exact Target, in a URL we put into that Template, I'd like to include the bold part below:   *(trying to make this readable, it's one URL)*

- www.ourcompany.com/getit
- ?fname=Anthony
- &lname=Malena
- &dog=Yes
- **&etid=abcde12345vwxyz67890**

where "etid" would be an identifier that points to the (later created) **Individual Email Result** object record that shows up in Salesforce.  We need to link a couple objects to that "IER" record to pass data, etc.

Since the record is not created until AFTER each email is sent, I'm sure I don't have access to it DURING the send (especially a bulk send), but I have to assume there is an Exact Target "ID" I can use.   "IER" has a "Merge ID" field that looks usable, but I can find no joy anywhere else I look for help - including Exact Target itself.

**Task/Activity** is one of the records which is **CREATED when the above URL is clicked**.  The "etid" would populate a **Lookup to "IER"** in my scenario.

Help?

---

**Update:** 2014-08-21

Received a response from the helpful gentleman in ET's Premier Support department... this may lead to the solution.

> Merge ID is a field on the Individual Email Result object, it contains
>   a the ID of the Email Send object and the Contact/Lead ID concatenated
>   together.
>
> Example MergeID Value: a09i000000CqxhjAAB00Qi000000SSLHFEA5
>
> a09i000000CqxhjAAB is the ID of the Email Send Object
>   00Qi000000SSLHFEA5 is the ID of the Lead object
>
> Support is not exactly sure what this field is used for but I would
>   assume it is related to the tracking push process in order to prevent
>   duplicates from being created.